# Non-reducing variant of the ANY() function that respects NaN

Tags: python, pandas

Hard to explain in words but the expample should be clear:

```
df = DataFrame( { 'x':[0,1], 'y':[np.NaN,0], 'z':[0,np.NaN] }, index=['a','b'] )

   x   y   z
a  0 NaN   0
b  1   0 NaN
```

I want to replace all non-NaN values with a '1', if there is a '1' anywhere in that row.  Just like this:

```
   x   y   z
a  0 NaN   0
b  1   1 NaN
```

This sort of works, but unfortunately overwrites the NaN

`df[ df.any(1) ] = 1`

```
   x   y  z
a  0 NaN  0
b  1   1  1
```

I thought there might be some non-reducing form of any (like cumsum is a non-reducing form of sum), but I can't find anything like that so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine a multiplication by zero (to give an empty frame but which remembers nan locations) with an `add` on `axis=0`:

```
>>> df
   x   y   z
a  0 NaN   0
b  1   0 NaN
>>> (df * 0).add(df.any(1), axis=0)
   x   y   z
a  0 NaN   0
b  1   1 NaN
```

Comment: Thanks!  Kinda hoping for something simpler but that works and it's helpful to see this approach.